# Mentioning a tag when posting a channel message from a teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I would very much like to mention a tag when creating a teams message. I read the tag ID from Microsoft graph (I've also tried fetching tag id from an incoming message).

I can do this as my self using Microsoft Graph api with the following payload

```
{
"body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<div>New incident ##### assigned to <at id=\"0\">App operations</at></div>"
},
"mentions": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "mentionText": "Operations",
        "mentioned": {
            "application": null,
            "device": null,
            "user": null,
            "conversation": null,
            "tag": {
                "id": "my tag Id which I got using graph lookup",
                "displayName": "App operations"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

Is this at all possible using the bot framework? Can the payload be manipulated to do this?

Comment: Right now it is not supported using bot.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT is it possible from app at all or is it just possible when logged in as a person?

Comment: You can use the MS graph inside of the bot

Comment: How would one authenticate against MS graph as a bot?

Comment: Try [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph). Follow this to [Add authentication to a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Caadv2). You will need to add the required permission and call the required API in sample.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT doesn't that require a user interaction?

Comment: Yes, Please have a look at this [Get access without user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#4-get-an-access-token) You can use application permissions and it will not require anyone to sign-in and you will get token for the tenant.

Comment: But how do I then post the message? When I call the chatmessage post endpoint I get a forbidden response, stating 'Requires one of Teamwork.Migrate.All or ChannelMessage.ReadWrite.All. The ChannelMessage.ReadWrite.All is not  available to the the app registration without a user and the Teamwork.Migrate.All requires the channel to be created in migration mode. 

How should I do this without a user?

Comment: I am really sorry about the response, I have been in misunderstanding with another Graph API call. It seems like it can't be done with the application permission.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT thank you for the clarification. With the blog post introducing Tags in Teams the focus was very much on on-call teams and operations, thus allowing apps to use tags makes sense to me. This way the app could have a channel for incidents and tag different teams. How can one engage with the Bot framework sdk team regarding mentioning tags in messages?

Comment: Like right now, it is not supported to mention tag using bot, if you find some Microsoft blog/post/doc could you please share?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it is not supported to mention a tag using bot. The possible workaround is to use Graph API in the bot. To do that you can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph). Follow this to [Add authentication to a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Caadv2). You will need to add the required permission and call the required API in sample.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, got dragged into other work. Will verify shortly.

Comment: Am I correct when I understand the "Add authentication to a bot" that it requires a user to sign in and post the message as the user? 

In this case, the trigger is a message from an external system, and we have various mappings between incoming notification and the tag's we wish to mention in teams.